# Android Adb install error

Tags: android

I try to install my .apk to my phone, not simulator

./adb install -r myapp.apk

I got Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your new apk and old apk are signed using different certificates.  It might be one is using a production key and one is using a debug key.  Or you generated the builds on 2 separate machines using different keys.

You can either use the same key to fix the issue or do `adb uninstall com.yourapp.package` and then re-install the app.

Answer (score 1):

different certificates causes
uninstall old one and reinstall new one will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Sign the APK with V1 enabled. 
In Android Studio --> build --> Generate signed APK --> enable V1(jar signature)
[image]